# Linux High availability and, DRBD, Heartbeat

Tags: linux

how to run the bash file if node 1 or 2 changes from secondary to primary in high availability?

i want to run my bash file in linux if my secondary server change from secondary to primary in high availability.

Answer (score 0):

I think  that you can write a deamon service to check DRBD state (run in both nodes). When DRBD state changed to become primary node, you will run your script.

Keywork: Implement failoverd service.

Ref: [DRBD Automatic Failover](http://ashish1099.github.io/blog/2014/12/26/drbd-automatic-failover-without-cluster/)